# ReactJS: Empty component's old fetched data before fetching again

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-hooks

I am fetching remote data from my React component. When data is ready, child components are rendered. While data is loading, the 'Data is loading ....' text is displayed.

When the component is rendered for the second time due to the `props` change, I set the previous data to `null` in order to show that new data is loading.

```
const List = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {  
    setItems(null);

    fetch(`http://some_url_to_fetch_items.com?PAGE=${props.page}`)
    .then((data) => {
       setItems(data);
    })   
  }, [props.page]);

  if (!items) {
    return "Data is loading ......."
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <li>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

The problem of this approach is that when the component is rendered for the second time the `setItems(null);` code is not executed immediately (probably because `useEffect` is executed asynchronously) and the component re-renderes 3 times instead of expected 2:

- 1-st re-render because of the props change (BUT with old data, since `setItems(null)` is executed too late)
- 2-nd re-render after `setItems(null)` is finally executed
- 3-rd re-render after data is fetched

I understand what the problem with my approach is. But I don't see another way. 
It is mandatory to use hooks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want to refetch EVERY time your component re-renders? Usually you would just fetch on initial render. That's the point of saving the data in state. How often does your data change? If you want to load new data on re-render, just set it again on rerender, there's no need to "clear" old data.

Comment: Also, you say you want to show "loading" when fetching new data. Therefore your component HAS to render once to show "loading" and again once data has been fetched.

Comment: @JMadelaine  I do not refetch EVERY time my component re-renders, only when `props` change.  For a passed through props page number I need to fetch corresponding items. Imagine any list with pagination, a user can choose a page - that is how often my data change. The state is used only for displaying "Data is loading ..." status. if I don't "clear" old data, how can I display that status without re-rendering old items?

Comment: @JMadelaine As I said, two renders ('loading', then with data) is fine. I only need to get rid of the first one - with the old data

Comment: A quick fix would be to add a key prop to your List: `<List key={page} page={page} />`. When the value for `page` changes, the `List` component will be unmounted, and a new one rendered. The new one will not have any previous data in it, so you will only get 2 renders instead of 3. This means you don't have to set previous data to null anymore. If you do this, you'll need to check that the component is still mounted in your `useEffect` before calling `setItems`, otherwise you'll be trying to set state on an unmounted component. You can write `if(setItems) { setItems(data) }`.

Comment: Changing the key prop is a bit hacky though, so I would investigate other ways to solve your issue. Maybe you should pass the data into the list instead of the list being responsible for fetching data, and have the page state and data both inside the parent component.

Comment: @JMadelaine Thank you for your suggestions, they are very useful. Could you please create an answer and copy them to it?

Comment: I've added my comments as an answer :)

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your issue, could you set it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add a key prop to your List:

```
<List key={page} page={page} />
```

When the value for page changes, the List component will be unmounted, and a new one rendered. The new one will not have any previous data in it, so you will only get 2 renders instead of 3.

This means you don't have to set previous data to `null` anymore.

If you do this, you'll need to check that the component is still mounted in your `useEffect` before calling `setItems`, otherwise you'll be trying to set state on an unmounted component. You can write:

```
if(setItems) {
  setItems(data)
}
```

Changing the key prop is a bit hacky though, so I would investigate other ways to solve your issue.

Maybe you should pass the data into the list instead of the list being responsible for fetching data, and have the page state and data both inside the parent component?

For now though, changing the key using the page should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this method  : 

  useEffect(() => {  
       fetch(`http://some_url_to_fetch_items.com?PAGE=${props.page}`)
        .then((data) => {
           setItems(data);
        })   
      }, []);

     return (
        <ul>
          {items? items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item}</li>
          )):"Data is Loading..."}
        </ul>
      )
```